# Installing xcolor

Tags: hyperref, color, installing, links

I get the error:

```
! Package hyperref Error: This color specification is not supported
(hyperref)                without package `xcolor' in
(hyperref)                `linkbordercolor=111'.

See the hyperref package documentation for explanation.
```

I installed it from http://www.ukern.de/tex/xcolor.html under the location:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor
```

And put the `.pro` file under:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011basic/texmf/dvips/xcolor
```

Still getting the error. Any clues?

EDIT:

http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf

> Usually, you will have to run some kind of ﬁlename database update in
>   order to make the ﬁles known and quickly searchable to the TEX system

Comment: sudo apt install texlive-pictures sudo apt update it works fine, texlive-pictures has xcolor pakage.

Answer (score 4):

Short: To update your TEXMF database run `texhash`.

Long:

I would always install packages from CTAN, e.g. 
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor, in the case of `xcolor`, but the author's website is of course also fine.

The README file contains installation instructions:

```
Installation instructions
=========================

Extract all package files:
  `latex xcolor.ins'

Put the generated files to their respective locations
within the TeX installation:
  *.sty -> /tex/latex/xcolor/
  *.def -> /tex/latex/xcolor/
  *.pro -> /dvips/xcolor/

Create the documentation:
  `latex xcolor.dtx'
  `latex xcolor.dtx'
  `makeindex -s gind.ist xcolor.idx'
  `latex xcolor.dtx'
  `latex xcolor.dtx'

Run the test files (N=1,2,...):
  `latex xcolorN.tex'
  `latex xcolorN.tex'
```

However, TeX Live comes with a **package manager** called `tlmgr` (not included in the version delivered by Ubuntu or Debian). With this manager you can  install `xcolor` simply using:

```
tlmgr install xcolor
```

Which will update the database as well. Note that you can update all installed packages using:

```
tlmgr update --self --all
```

I personally would simply install the full TeX Live (if you have the HD space of ~2.5GB) using:

```
tlmgr install scheme-full
```

Then you don't have these issue any longer.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have set the color as

```
linkbordercolor=1 1 1
```

try it this way:

```
linkbordercolor={1 1 1}
```

Comment: *Hat tip*. I was using a reputable template, tisk tisk.

Comment: @Aram: If `linkbordercolor` is used as package option all spaces will be removed. Using `\hypersetup{..}` instead afterwards is more recommended.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and it turns out I forgot to include

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

So despite the package being installed it was not included, thus yielding the error message.